# Bad practice to put = inside javascript if statement?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript : assign variable in if condition statement, good practice or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576571/javascript-assign-variable-in-if-condition-statement-good-practice-or-not)

Is it bad practice to assign/evaluate things inside an if statement?

eg.

```
var foo;
var bar = function() { .. }

if(foo = bar()) {
    ..
}
```

Comment: You could have it all (excluding the `var` declaration) in the `if()` if you really want to: `var foo, bar; if( foo = (bar = function() { /***/ })() ) { /***/ }`

Answer (score 3):

Functionality-wise there's absolutely nothing wrong with that.  But if you're going for readability, keep in mind that more junior members of your team (if any) may have a tougher time with less straight forward syntax as this.

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine and is not bad practice in Javascript.

JSLint might not agree with me though ;-)

Comment: It's *not* bad practice? Based on what?