# Equivalent of PHP's `if ($variable = 5){}`

Tags: javascript, if-statement, expression

I do not know whether this has a term for itself or not, but, in PHP I can do:

```
if ($variable = 5)
{
    echo $variable; // 5
}
```

Where, the same for JS fails:

```
if (var variable = 5)
{
    echo variable; // Unexpected token var 
}
```

Is there an equivalent?

Comment: Seems to work with `var variable; if (variable = 5) ...`.

Comment: No, declaration requires a `var` *statement*, and there is not an expression equivalent.

Comment: What's the goal ? The PHP code you show looks just like something that should not be allowed in order to have maintainable code.

Comment: This is called putting an assignment inside a conditional, and it is a bad practice. [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576571/javascript-assign-variable-in-if-condition-statement-good-practice-or-not)

Comment: Oh, I see. It's meant for the case 5 is replaced by something dynamically computed, I suppose.

Comment: It was initially meant for `if (settings.elementID && var element = document.getElementById( settings.elementID ) && !element.getAttribute('data-added')`, I just stripped it down for Q.

Comment: This line is long enough... You could simply declare and assign the var at first line and test it at the following line.

Comment: Well, after getting the proof that it's not possible, I did return back to normal way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot define a variable inside `if` block. So, the answer is no, you cannot do this in javascript. In PHP, a variable definition will return `true` which will drive the `if`.

But, an assignment statement returns true, so you can use:

```
var $variable;
if($variable = 5) {
    alert($variable);
}
```

Comment: More specifically: there is no variable definition in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

`var variable` should be at the start of the function block, not inside an expression.

```
var variable;
if( variable = 5) {
    alert(variable);
}
```

Of course, it's completely redundant...

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the variable `variable` before the `if` clause:

```
var variable;

if (variable = 5)
{
    console.log( variable ); // logs 5
}
```