# Assigning values inside conditional operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

Is it good practice that assigning value to variables inside conditional operator ? This is about conditonal/turnery operator not about if statement

```
 a===1 ? (b=2) : (b=0)
```

I am getting lint warning when using this method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign variable in if condition statement, good practice or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576571/assign-variable-in-if-condition-statement-good-practice-or-not)

Comment: Why not keep it simple? i.e. `b = a===1 ? 2 : 0;`

Comment: consider this  situation  
a===1 ? (b=2,c=1):(b=0,c=3)

Comment: Readability is important factor, I would use `if(a===1){b=2;c=1;}else{b=0;c=3;}`

Comment: Your linter is right in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, using an assignment as an assignment is rarely a good idea - code is much easier to read and understand when conditions only *test* conditions, rather than when those conditions also have side-effects. In this case, you can fix it putting `2` and `0` as the expressions on the right:

```
const b = a === 1 ? 2 : 0;
```

The only time I think an assignment inside a conditional might *possibly* look cleaner than the alternative is when iterating over a global regular expression manually to extract matched groups (this is not using the *conditional operator*, but the principle is similar):

```js
const regex = /\w(?=(\w))/g;
const str = 'foo';

let match;
while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Alternatives, without assigning inside the `while` condition, are:

```js
// Requires while(true):
const regex = /\w(?=(\w))/g;
const str = 'foo';

while (true) {
  const match = regex.exec(str);
  if (!match) {
    break;
  }
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

or

```js
// A bit WET:
const regex = /\w(?=(\w))/g;
const str = 'foo';

let match = regex.exec(str);
while (match) {
  console.log(match[1]);
  match = regex.exec(str);
}
```

But that might be opinion-based.

Note that (ab)using the conditional operator as a replacement for `if/else` is common to see in *minified code*, but that's perfectly fine, because minified code isn't meant to be read, only parsed. It's also a valid technique in code golf.

If you want to assign to multiple variables inside a conditional, you can use destructuring:

```js
const a = 689;
const [b, c] = a === 1 ? [2, 1] : [0, 3];
console.log(c);
```

Or, if the variables are strongly related, which sounds likely, it would probably be better to use an object (or array) instead of multiple standalone variables:

```js
const a = 689;
const obj = a === 1 ? { b: 2, c: 1 } : { b: 0, c: 3 };
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: consider this situation a===1 ? (b=2,c=1):(b=0,c=3) 
The reason I followed this is because, based on a single condition I want to assign values to two variables. If I follow this, I could avoid one condition checking

Comment: You could use destructuring: `const [b, c] = a === 1 ? [2, 1] : [0, 3];` You could also use a plain `if/else` statement if using `const` isn't required (though `const` is preferable when possible). If `b` and `c` are strongly related variables, like if they represent similar things, I'd recommend using an object or array instead of two separate variables

Comment: can you write this as the answer, I feel this is more appropriate. I will accept