# How to assign the value inside the if condition in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I don't know if **vue** recognize the syntax below:

```
if(var error = errors.description){
    location.href = "/redirect?topic="+error;
}
```

The code above returns a compilation error:

> ERROR in ./resources/js/forms/Signup.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--4-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./resources/js/forms/Signup.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)

Someone knows how to assign a variable inside the if else condition?

Comment: Vue is just JavaScript. The code you've provided is not valid JavaScript. Why not just move the assignment to the preceding line and then test for `if (error) {`?

Comment: @skirtle I'm trying to minimize for one line only. just like in php https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/php-variable-assignment-within-if-statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather a JavaScript syntax issue than Vue. While I **highly** recommend not assigning within a conditional, you can do so only by either declaring the variable earlier or not explicitly declaring it at all, i.e. by removing the `var` above.

Here's an example with your above code:

```js
if(error = errors.description){
    location.href = "/redirect?topic="+error;
}
```

To be clear, it is highly recommended not to do the above, or at the very least declare `var error` earlier so that you don't accidentally modify a global variable, like so:

```js
let error;
if(error = errors.description){
    location.href = "/redirect?topic="+error;
}
```

Of course the most explicit and safe solution to avoid confusion about the assignment is to simply do it earlier:

```js
let error = errors.description;
if (error) {
    location.href = "/redirect?topic="+error;
}
```

There has been some [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576571/assign-variable-in-if-condition-statement-good-practice-or-not) about whether assignment within conditionals is good practice. However, on a completely separate note it is widely agreed that assigning variables that haven't been declared with `var`, `let`, or `const` is dangerous as you could accidentally modify variables of higher scope.