# Javascript: Assign a variable and check if falsy at the same time

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in javascript to both assign and check for undefined (or null or whatever) in one line like this:

```
if (let myVar = DoSomethingAndReturnValue()) {
    // DoSomethingAndReturnValue() returned a falsy value and so myVar is falsy
   return
}
// myVar is now assigned with some value we can do something with it.
```

Comment: yes but i dont think you can declare a new variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2576606/1772933

Comment: you would initialize myVar before the comparison....

Comment: What is the goal? You can do `let x = foo() ?? "fallback"` if you want to avoid `null` or `undefined` assignments. If you just want to exit early if the variable is falsy, then you need to declare it and then check it. It's ...1 extra line. Hardly something that will have a huge impact on your code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a global variable but does it.

```
if (!(myVar = DoSomethingAndReturnValue())) {
   console.log(2);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't advise it. It's bad for more reasons than just the global.

Comment: I personally am never gonna do this, in my code. Just trying to help the OP.

Comment: Yeah, assigning a local var first would be better than the global. Too bad can't do it all at once. It has been a couple of decades since I programmed in C and I seem to dimly remember doing this assign/compare pattern back then then. Every so often which I still could. And this does work!